# Merge Rows by ID and Date

Tags: r, date, merge

I am newbie at R and I have been searching on how to solve the following problem.

I have a df that looks like:

id------------Date ------------OB1------ OB2----- OB3
1   ------- 2017-01-01  ---------  1  ---------  0--------- 0
2  ------- 2006-01-05  ---------  1  ---------  0---------  0
2  ------- 2007-04-19  ---------  0  ---------  1---------  0
3  ------- **2015-02-23**  ---------  0  ---------  0---------  1
3    ------- **2015-02-23**  --------- 1  ---------  0---------  0

What I have to achieve is shown here:

id------------Date ------------OB1------ OB2----- OB3
1   ------- 2017-01-01  ---------  1  ---------  0--------- 0
2  ------- 2006-01-05  ---------  1  ---------  0---------  0
2  ------- 2007-04-19  ---------  0  ---------  1---------  0
3  ------- **2015-02-23**  ---------  **1**  ---------  0---------  **1**

This is, to combine rows, by id and date.

If there is value '1' for OB3 in a date and value '1' for OB1 in the same date (for the same ID) the result must be value '1' for OB1, value '1' for 'OB3' and a single date

I have been trying to apply some solutions explained here:
[Merge rows having same values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324894/merge-rows-having-same-values-in-multiple-columns)

But it didn't work

EDIT: OB1, OB2, OBS3 are boolean values
Thanks for your help!

EDIT 2: aggregate(. ~ ID + Date, df, any) works!

---

## Sample data

**Input Data**

```
structure(list(ID = c(-1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("2008-01-15", "2011-01-21", "2011-01-21"), `OBS1` = c(0, 0, 0), `OBS2` = c(0, 0, 0), `OBS3` = c(0, 0, 0), `OBS4` = c(0, 0, 0), `OBS5` = c(0, 0, 0), `OBS6` = c(0, 1, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "OBS1", "OBS2", "OBS3", "OBS4", "OBS5", "OBS6"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Output Data**

```
structure(list(ID = c(-1L, 1L), Date = c("2008-01-15", "2011-01-21"), `OBS1` = c(FALSE, FALSE), `OBS2` = c(FALSE, FALSE), `OBS3` = c(FALSE, FALSE), `OBS4` = c(FALSE, FALSE), `OBS5` = c(FALSE, FALSE), `OBS6` = c(FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "OBS1", "OBS2", "OBS3", "OBS4", "OBS5", "OBS6"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please include what exactly did not work in your question!

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ id + Date, df, sum)`

Comment: @alistaire with that sentence, I obtained for OB1 value '2' and for OB2 value '0'.

Comment: Maybe it is just `aggregate(. ~ Date, df[, -1], sum)`.

Comment: Replace `sum` with `any`?

Comment: @alistaire it seems to be working under a subset of the df (very large df)! I will test under the whole df and post the results.

Many thanks to all of you

Comment: Post an excerpt of your data or an exemplar sample with `dput` so people can actually look at what you got.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question already has been answered using base R's `aggregate()` function.

However, I felt challenged to turn the sample dataset as printed in the question into a reproducible example (*before* the OP edited the question to include the results of `dput()`).

In addition, the OP has mentioned he has a *"very large df"* which might be worthwhile to try a `data.table` approach.

#### Convert sample data into a dataframe

```r
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
df <- readr::read_file(
"id------------Date ------------OB1------ OB2----- OB3
1 ------- 2017-01-01 --------- 1 --------- 0--------- 0
2 ------- 2006-01-05 --------- 1 --------- 0--------- 0
2 ------- 2007-04-19 --------- 0 --------- 1--------- 0
3 ------- 2015-02-23 --------- 0 --------- 0--------- 1
3 ------- 2015-02-23 --------- 1 --------- 0--------- 0"
) %>% stringr::str_replace_all("[-]{2,}", " ") %>% 
  fread()
df
```

> ```r
>    id       Date   OB1   OB2   OB3
> 1:  1 2017-01-01  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 2:  2 2006-01-05  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 3:  2 2007-04-19 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 4:  3 2015-02-23 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> 5:  3 2015-02-23  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> ```

Note that `fread()` has recognised automatically the boolean columns.

#### Aggregate

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, any), by = .(id, Date)]
```

> ```r
>    id       Date   OB1   OB2   OB3
> 1:  1 2017-01-01  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 2:  2 2006-01-05  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 3:  2 2007-04-19 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 4:  3 2015-02-23  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> ```

In case, the OP expects integer values `0` and `1` instead of logical values, these can be created in one go:

```r
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(any(x))), by = .(id, Date)]
```

> ```r
>    id       Date OB1 OB2 OB3
> 1:  1 2017-01-01   1   0   0
> 2:  2 2006-01-05   1   0   0
> 3:  2 2007-04-19   0   1   0
> 4:  3 2015-02-23   1   0   1
> ```

Comment: Guau thank you!

I will try with this code, seems amazing