# Merging data.table rows based on dates

Tags: r, data.table

**Problem:**
I have records with a start and end date for an intervention and I want to merge the rows according to the following rule:

For each ID, any intervention that begins within one year of the last intervention ending, merge the rows so that the start_date is the earliest start date of the two rows, and the end_date is the latest end_date of the two rows.
I also want to keep track of intervention IDs if they are merged.

There can be five scenarios:

1. Two rows have the same start date, but different end dates.

`Start date....End date`

`Start date.........End date`

2. The period between row 2's start and end date lies within the period of row 1's start and end date.

`Start date...................End date`

`.......Start date...End date`

3. Row 2's intervention starts within Row 1's intervention period but ends later.

`Start date.....End date`

`.....Start date.............End date`

4. Row 2 starts within one year of the end of Row 1.

`Start date....End date`

`......................|....<= 1 year....|Start date...End date`

5. Row 2 starts over one year after the end of Row 1.

`Start date...End date`

`.....................|........ > 1 year..........|Start date...End date`

I want to merge rows in cases 1 to 4 but not 5.

**Data:**

```r
library(data.table)
sample_data <- data.table(id = c(rep(11, 3), rep(21, 4)),
    start_date = as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-12-01", "2015-06-01")),
    end_date = as.Date(c("2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-05-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-09-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-12-01")),
    intervention_id = as.character(1:7),
    all_ids = as.character(1:7))

> sample_data
   id start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
1: 11 2013-01-01 2013-06-01               1       1
2: 11 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               2       2
3: 11 2013-02-01 2013-05-01               3       3
4: 21 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               4       4
5: 21 2013-02-01 2013-09-01               5       5
6: 21 2013-12-01 2014-01-01               6       6
7: 21 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7
```

The final result should look like:

```
> merged_data
   id start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
1: 11 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               1 1, 2, 3
2: 21 2013-01-01 2014-01-01               4 4, 5, 6
3: 21 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7
```

I'm not sure if the `all_ids` column is the best way to keep track of the `intervention_id`'s so open to ideas for that. (The `intervention_id`'s don't need to be in order in the `all_ids` column.)

It doesn't matter what the value of the `intervention_id` column is where rows have been merged.

**What I tried:**

I started off by writing a function to deal with only those cases where the start date is the same. It's a very non-R, non-data.table way of doing it and therefore very inefficient.

```
mergestart <- function(unmerged) {
  n <- nrow(unmerged)
  mini_merged <- data.table(id = double(n),
                     start_date = as.Date(NA),
                     end_date = as.Date(NA),
                     intervention_id = character(n),
                     all_ids = character(n))

  merge_a <- function(unmerged, un_i, merged, m_i, no_of_records) {
    merged[m_i] <- unmerged[un_i]
    un_i <- un_i + 1

    while (un_i <= no_of_records) {
      if(merged[m_i]$start_date == unmerged[un_i]$start_date) {
        merged[m_i]$end_date <- max(merged[m_i]$end_date, unmerged[un_i]$end_date)
        merged[m_i]$all_ids <- paste0(merged[m_i]$all_ids, ",", unmerged[un_i]$intervention_id)
        un_i <- un_i + 1
      } else {
        m_i <- m_i + 1
        merged[m_i] <- unmerged[un_i]
        un_i <- un_i + 1

        merge_a(unmerged, un_i, merged, m_i, (no_of_records - un_i))
      }
    }
    return(merged)  
  }

  mini_merged <- merge_a(unmerged, 1, mini_merged, 1, n)
  return(copy(mini_merged[id != 0]))
}
```

Using this function on just one `id` gives:

```
> mergestart(sample_data[id == 11])
   id start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
1: 11 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               1     1,2
2: 11 2013-02-01 2013-05-01               3       3
```

To use the function on the whole dataset:

```
n <- nrow(sample_data)
all_merged <- data.table(id = double(n),
                     start_date = as.Date(NA),
                     end_date = as.Date(NA),
                     intervention_id = character(n),
                     all_ids = character(n))

start_i <- 1
for (i in unique(sample_data$id)) {
  id_merged <- mergestart(sample_data[id == i])

  end_i <- start_i + nrow(id_merged) - 1
  all_merged[start_i:end_i] <- copy(id_merged)
  start_i <- end_i
}
all_merged <- all_merged[id != 0]

> all_merged
   id start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
1: 11 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               1     1,2
2: 21 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               4       4
3: 21 2013-02-01 2013-09-01               5       5
4: 21 2013-12-01 2014-01-01               6       6
5: 21 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7
```

I also had a look at rolling joins but still can't get how to use it in this situation.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48747399/6170115 looked promising but I don't know how to integrate all the other conditions and track the intervention IDs with this method.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I wrote a function to tackle a similar problem [that's on Github](https://github.com/TelethonKids/biometrics/blob/master/R/group_interval.R) that groups hospital admission  records into episodes of care. You could use this, group by episode and treatment ids and summarise to find min and max dates. This function isn't computationally efficient and may take a while on large data sets.

Comment: This may get you started: [Consolidate rows based on date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046210/consolidate-rows-based-on-date-ranges?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are related questions [How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28938147/3817004) and [Consolidate rows based on date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39046210/3817004) but none of them has the additional requirements posed by the OP.

```
library(data.table)
# ensure rows are ordered
setorder(sample_data, id, start_date, end_date)
# find periods
sample_data[, period := {
  tmp <- as.integer(start_date)
  cumsum(tmp > shift(cummax(tmp + 365L), type = "lag", fill = 0L))
}, by = id][]
```

> ```
>    id start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids period
> 1: 11 2013-01-01 2013-06-01               1       1      1
> 2: 11 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               2       2      1
> 3: 11 2013-02-01 2013-05-01               3       3      1
> 4: 21 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               4       4      1
> 5: 21 2013-02-01 2013-09-01               5       5      1
> 6: 21 2013-12-01 2014-01-01               6       6      1
> 7: 21 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7      2
> ```

For the sake of simplicity, it is assumed that one year has 365 days which ignores leap years with 366 days. If leap years are to be considered, a more sophisticated date arithmetic is required.

Unfortunately, `cummax()` has no method for arguments of class `Date` or `IDate` (`data.table`'s integer version). Therefore, the coersion from `Date` to integer is required.

```
# aggregate
sample_data[, .(start_date = start_date[1L], 
                end_date = max(end_date), 
                intervention_id = intervention_id[1L], 
                all_ids = toString(intervention_id)), 
            by = .(id, period)]
```

> ```
>    id period start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
> 1: 11      1 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               1 1, 2, 3
> 2: 21      1 2013-01-01 2014-01-01               4 4, 5, 6
> 3: 21      2 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7
> ```

#### Edit: Correction

I just noted that I had misinterpreted OP's requirements. The OP has requested (emphasis mine):

> For each ID, any intervention that begins within one year of the last
>   intervention *ending*, merge the rows so that the start_date is the
>   earliest start date of the two rows, and the end_date is the latest
>   end_date of the two rows.

The solution above looks for gaps of one year in the sequence of `start_date` but not in the sequence of `start_date` and the preceeding `end_date` as requested. The corrected version is:

```
library(data.table)
# ensure rows are ordered
setorder(sample_data, id, start_date, end_date)
# find periods
sample_data[, period := cumsum(
  as.integer(start_date) > shift(
    cummax(as.integer(end_date) + 365L), type = "lag", fill = 0L))
  , by = id][]
# aggregate
sample_data[, .(start_date = start_date[1L], 
                end_date = max(end_date), 
                intervention_id = intervention_id[1L], 
                all_ids = toString(intervention_id)), 
            by = .(id, period)]
```

> ```
>    id period start_date   end_date intervention_id all_ids
> 1: 11      1 2013-01-01 2013-07-01               1 1, 2, 3
> 2: 21      1 2013-01-01 2014-01-01               4 4, 5, 6
> 3: 21      2 2015-06-01 2015-12-01               7       7
> ```

The result for the given sample dataset is identical for both versions which caused the error to slip through unrecognized.

#### Benchmark

The OP has mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586169/merging-data-table-rows-based-on-dates#comment92135567_52591732) that using `lubridate`'s date arithmetic has dramatically enlarged run times.

According to my benchmark below, the penalty of using  `end_date %m+% years(1)` is not that much. I have benchmarked three versions of the code:

- `v_1` is the corrected version from above.
- `v_2` pulls the type conversion and the data arithmetic out of the grouping part and creates two helper columns in advance.
- `v_3` is like `v_2` but uses `end_date %m+% years(1)`.

The benchmark is repeated for different problem sizes, i.e., total number of rows. Also, the number of different `id`s is varied as grouping may have an effect on performance. [According to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586169/merging-data-table-rows-based-on-dates/52591732?noredirect=1#comment92174402_52591732), his full dataset of 500 k rows has 250 k unique `id`s which corresponds to an `id_share` of 0.5 (50%). In the benchmark `id_share`s of 0.5, 0.2, and 0.01 (50%, 20%, 1%) are simulated.

As `sample_data` is modified, each run starts with a fresh copy.

```
library(bench)
library(magrittr)
bm <- press(
  id_share = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.01),
  n_row = c(1000L, 10000L, 1e5L),
  {
    n_id <- max(1L, as.integer(n_row * id_share))
    print(sprintf("Number of ids: %i", n_id))
    set.seed(123L)
    sample_data_0 <- lapply(seq(n_id), function(.id) data.table(
      start_date = as.IDate("2000-01-01") + cumsum(sample(0:730, n_row / n_id, TRUE))
    )) %>% 
      rbindlist(idcol = "id") %>% 
      .[, end_date := start_date + sample(30:360, n_row, TRUE)] %>% 
      .[, intervention_id := as.character(.I)]
    mark(
      v_1 = {
        sample_data <- copy(sample_data_0)
        setorder(sample_data, id, start_date, end_date)
        sample_data[, period := cumsum(
          as.integer(start_date) > shift(
            cummax(as.integer(end_date) + 365L), type = "lag", fill = 0L))
          , by = id]
        sample_data[, .(start_date = start_date[1L], 
                        end_date = max(end_date), 
                        intervention_id = intervention_id[1L], 
                        all_ids = toString(intervention_id)), 
                    by = .(id, period)]
      },
      v_2 = {
        sample_data <- copy(sample_data_0)
        setorder(sample_data, id, start_date, end_date)
        sample_data[, `:=`(start = as.integer(start_date), 
                           end = as.integer(end_date) + 365)]
        sample_data[, period := cumsum(start > shift(cummax(end), type = "lag", fill = 0L))
                    , by = id]
        sample_data[, .(start_date = start_date[1L], 
                        end_date = max(end_date), 
                        intervention_id = intervention_id[1L], 
                        all_ids = toString(intervention_id)), 
                    by = .(id, period)]
        },
      v_3 = {
        sample_data <- copy(sample_data_0)
        setorder(sample_data, id, start_date, end_date)
        sample_data[, `:=`(start = as.integer(start_date), 
                           end = as.integer(end_date %m+% years(1)))]
        sample_data[, period := cumsum(start > shift(cummax(end), type = "lag", fill = 0L))
                    , by = id]
        sample_data[, .(start_date = start_date[1L], 
                        end_date = max(end_date), 
                        intervention_id = intervention_id[1L], 
                        all_ids = toString(intervention_id)), 
                    by = .(id, period)]
      },
      check = FALSE,
      min_iterations = 3
    )
  }
)

ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

The result shows that the number of groups, i.e., number of unique `id`, does have a stronger effect on the run time than the different code versions. In case of many groups, the creation of helper columns before grouping (`v_2`) gains performance.

Comment: Re as.integer, I guess they should just `:=` overwrite with IDate before starting, eh.

Comment: @Frank `cummax()` does work neither with `Date` nor `IDate`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @Uwe. I'm going to see if I can use `lubridate`'s `%m+%` operator somewhere in the arithmetic, then convert to integer for the `cummax`. Just so you know, your whole procedure took about 20 seconds for 500k rows!

Comment: Using `lubridate` to add a year before converting to integer `tmp_yr <- as.integer(start_date %m+% years(1))`, extends the run time from about 20 seconds to over 15 mins.

Comment: @Uwe What is the purpose of `cummax()`? Isn't it operating on individual elements of the vector?

Comment: `cummax()` is the _cumulative maximum_. `cummax(x)` returns a vector of the same length as `x` which contains the largest value encountered _so far_. So, `cummax(c(1, 0, 3))` returns `[1] 1 1 3`.

Comment: Using helper columns and `%m+%`, the run time was under 20 seconds on my full dataset of ~500k rows. Love your work @Uwe.

Comment: Great! How many different `id` does your full dataset have? I am asking because the number of groups seems to have strong impact on run time.

Comment: There are about 250k unique `id`s. So I think you are right about the groups.

Comment: I have re-run the benchmark to include the case of an `id_share` of 0.5 (50%) according to your 250 k groups / 500 k rows.